# Julia - Multiple conditions for filtering array

Tags: arrays, filter, julia

Given an array like:

```
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "Computer science"
 "Artificial intelligence"
 "Machine learning"
 "Algorithm"
 "Mathematics"
```

How does one filter it by multiple conditions in Julia? For example, I want to obtain all the
values that are not "Computer science" or "Artificial intelligence", hence, I want to obtain:

```
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "Machine learning"
 "Algorithm"
 "Mathematics"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
julia> x = ["Computer science", "Artificial intelligence", "Machine learning", "Algorithm", "Mathematics"]
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "Computer science"
 "Artificial intelligence"
 "Machine learning"
 "Algorithm"
 "Mathematics"

# Note the double parentheses, in order to build the
# ("Computer science", "Artificial intelligence") tuple
#
# It would also be possible (but probably less efficient) to put
# those values in a vector
julia> filter(!in(("Computer science", "Artificial intelligence")), x)
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "Machine learning"
 "Algorithm"
 "Mathematics"
```

**Edit:** as mentioned in comments, if the list of values to filter out is longer, it might be more efficient to build a `Set` instead of a `Tuple`:

```
julia> filter(!in(Set(("Computer science", "Artificial intelligence"))), x)
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "Machine learning"
 "Algorithm"
 "Mathematics"
```

Comment: It should be noted that if the list of values for filtering is longer than just few elements they should be put into a `Set` that has O(ln(n)) search time rather than O(n) in case of a tuple or vector. For short filtering lists the proposed approach will be indeed fastest.

Comment: Good idea @PrzemyslawSzufel! I edited my answer to reflect your comment, thanks!